# Reflection - creating datatype from a string literal value

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Function Test()
    Dim o As Object = getVariable("Integer")
    If TypeOf o Is Integer Then
        'Do some processing on the integer
    ElseIf TypeOf o Is Decimal Then
        'Do some processing on the integer
    End If
End Function

Public Function getVariable(ByVal strDataType As String)
    If strDataType = "Integer" Then
        Return New Integer
    ElseIf strDataType = "Decimal" Then
        Return New Decimal
    ElseIf strDataType = "Double" Then
        Return New Double
    End If
End Function
```

I suspect there is an easier way (fewer lines of code) of doing this with Reflection?

Comment: Use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a1b71ta.aspx) instead of reflection.

Comment: And use `Enum` instead of strings, and does `VB.NET` have  a `default` keyword?

Comment: @ja72: VB.NET has the almighty `Nothing`. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) together with [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
Public Function getVariable(ByVal strDataType As String)
  Return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(strDataType))
End Function
```

For `strDataType` you need to be using `System.Int32`, `System.Decimal` and `System.Double` respectively. If you want to keep it as `Integer` etc., you need to incorporate string translation, for example, have a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`, with entries like `("Integer", "System.Int32")`.

Comment: Thanks +1.  Do you know if it is possible to do this with reference object e.g. getObject("Person") or getObject("string")?

Comment: @w0051977: `GetType` works for reference types as well. Just make sure you classes are fully qualified, i.e. `YourAppName.Person` and `System.String`.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is what ars you trying to solve? Activator will work. Are trying to create a factory or an IOC container. Could you provide more detail? You could also create a dictionary were the key is of type string and then item stores delegates used to actual create the type.